# Improving Newton's Method Recursion

Tags: python

I have solved a previous problem and now I am stuck with this one. 
It is asking for an improvement of the previous solution which I posted below, but can't quite understand what the problem is asking. (Also, can't really figure out how to solve it.) 
Please help 
thanks.

Problem:
Elena complains that the recursive newton function in Project 2 includes
an extra argument for the estimate. The function’s users should not have to
provide this value, which is always the same, when they call this function.
Modify the definition of the function so that it uses a keyword parameter
with the appropriate default value for this argument, and call the function
without a second argument to demonstrate that it solves this problem.

Here is my code:

```
def newtonSquare(x, estimate):
    if abs(x-estimate ** 2) <= 0.000001:
        return estimate
    else:
        return newtonSquare(x, (estimate + x / estimate) / 2)

def main():
    num = int(raw_input('Enter a positive number >> '))
    print newtonSquare(num, 1.0)

main()
```

Comment: Too bad there's no option to vote to close for [insufficient reading of the widely-available documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)...

Comment: Stedy >> Nope it is not. I am doing it for fun.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a complaint that when somebody calls `newtonSquare`, they always do so with an initial estimate of 1.0. To set it as the default value, unless you explicitly provide it, you only have to modify the definition of the function to:

```
def newtonSquare(x, estimate = 1.0):
```

Comment: >> Michael Foukarakis thank you for your help. I guess I was thinking too much into it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the default value solution of Michael's is defining the recursive function local to the newtonSquare function:

```
def newtonSquare(x):

    def f(x, estimate):
        if abs(x-estimate ** 2) <= 0.000001:
            return estimate
        else:
            return f(x, (estimate + x / estimate) / 2)

    return f(x, 1.0)

def main():
    num = int(raw_input('Enter a positive number >> '))
    print newtonSquare(num)

main()
```

In this case having the default value is nicer and more flexible though, but this can still be a useful pattern.